# How can I limit a DNS name to be only resolved to services with a specific label in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kube-dns

I can resolve a DNS name on the internal kubernetes DNS with a value like: http://serviceNameExampleAbc.default.svc.cluster.local where `serviceExampleAbc` relates to the IP of the service by name `serviceExampleAbc`...

However, how can I instead only resolve this to the service IP only if it has a specific label to it?

For example `http://serviceNameExampleAbc.servicesWithXyzLabelOnly.default.svc.cluster.local` would only resolve to `serviceNameExampleAbc`'s IP **if** it has a label defined for it like below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: serviceNameExampleAbc
  labels:
    xyz: abcxyzexmaple
...
```

Comment: kubernetes network policies or similar are you looking for ? IP expect if request is coming from a specific namespace or label thn will be able resolve the IP but get denied by the Policy. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the K8s **[network polcies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/)** to block the traffic across the namespace or services.

So with network policy, you will be able to restrict the traffic across the namespaces, PODs based on the labels, selectors etc.

With **network policy** service will be able to resolve the **IP** in **DNS** but the Network policy won't allow further to connect to **end** **service**.

**Example**

Allow traffic from some PODs in another namespace

```
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: web-allow-all-ns-db
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: web
  ingress:
    - from:
      - namespaceSelector:     #All pods in namespace with label app=db-ns
          matchLabels:
            team: operations  
        podSelector:           #Chooses pods with app=db
          matchLabels:
            app: db
```

here is the list of policies you can refer : https://github.com/ahmetb/kubernetes-network-policy-recipes

Comment: Thanks, although this is helpful it does not really directly answer the question. In the case of this being used in a nginx server, it'll likely timeout a connection instead of responding with a 502 bad gateway.

Comment: Sorry didn’t get how you are forwarding traffic nginx server there middle to handle req? Not sure about arch else in nginx you can handle timeout.